# How to change the background color of both li and a when the li is hovered?

Tags: css, hover, html-lists

So this is my problem, check this website:

http://rawgameshop.com/test.php

On the left hand side where it says "Browse games more easily!" I have 2 li elements with links inside them. What I want to achieve is that BOTH the li and a change their colors when the li is hovered.

If you try it now the a element will only change its color when hovered exactly over it, and not the li.

I tried the following:

```
<a href="#"><li>UNDER 5€</li></a>
```

But that left some nasty line across the li element (right under the letters) even thought I put text-decoration:none everywhere.

Comment: can you use jQuery for this?

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML and CSS here.

Comment: Wrapping LI in a link is invalid html!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change your markup to this:

```
<li><a href='#'>Text</a></li>
```

Then in your css you can just do:

```
li a:hover{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Since your `a` is now providing the width for the `li` tag, the whole thing will change color.

Comment: And if you want the anchor to fill the entire list item use li a{display:block;}

Comment: @JoeSpurling you actually don't even have to do that, both are `inline` elements so the `li` will only wrapp as much space as the `a` takes up. But what you suggest will allow you to achieve some different things.

Comment: Did that, there seems to be a problem with the top and bot padding, it just won't work the way it does when it's hovered. I don't know why.

Comment: @DrazenBebic what's the issue? it seems to be hovering just fine when I look at it.

Comment: @DrazenBebic it might help if you create a jsfiddle so we can see exactly what you are doing. ryan's advice should have done the trick

Comment: Hang on a sec, I'll make the jsfiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fc79d/

What I want to accomplish is that the height of the li in its normal state is the same as when its hovered. But this is not the case cause the top and bottom padding seems to be missing.

Comment: @DrazenBebic are you going for this: http://jsfiddle.net/fc79d/1/ or for this: http://jsfiddle.net/fc79d/2/ ?? The thing with padding is that is enlarges your element without increasing the width/height properties. I would go with 1 and avoid padding altogether.

Comment: Well, my answer was deleted, so I'll give the link here again: http://jsfiddle.net/JL83x/ I think, that should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

First of all list items should be within a list element rather than anchors. If you want them to contain links then place the anchors within the list items.

In response to your question I would use

```
ul:hover li, ul:hover li a {background:red;}
```

Comment: Sorry I think I misread your question as you wanted both list items to change colour. I'll respond again.